# How to switch track formats in exo player from available one(HLS)?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

`player.getCurrentTrackGroups().get(0).formats;`

I see this method where I can get the array of available formats but I don't know how to select one from these. The backend supports HLS where different formats have different resolutions. Exo player automatically selects a format according to network speed but I want to do this manually as they do on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

```
[took help from the accepted answer][1]
DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();

//insert above two lines in your initPlayer() method

//this method does the actual work     
private void applySelection(int trackIndex) {

    int videoRendererIndex = 0;

    MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();

    //This logic is to find the find the video renderer index
    for (int i = 0; i < mappedTrackInfo.length; i++) {
        TrackGroupArray trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(i);
        if (trackGroups.length != 0) {
            switch (player.getRendererType(i)) {
                case C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO:
                    videoRendererIndex = i;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo != null ? mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(videoRendererIndex) : null;
    int groupIndex = 0;//which group has the the formats you want to use, in my case it was 0.
    //You can use the debugger or you can Log the whole trackGroup to see its details.
    DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override = new DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(groupIndex, trackIndex);

    parametersBuilder = new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder(this);
    if (trackGroups != null) {
        parametersBuilder.setSelectionOverride(videoRendererIndex, trackGroups, override);
        trackSelector.setParameters(parametersBuilder);
    }
}

//incase you want to switch to auto quality select, insert these lines you code
trackSelector.clearSelectionOverride(0,trackGroups);
```

Comment: where to call applySelection() function.

Comment: @DevMobApp I know i am more than a little late.. You have to create a dialog by yourself and allow user to choose a option. Pass the index of selected option to this method `applySelection()`.